# Why scandir.walk and os.walk get stuck in a specific directory?

Tags: python, linux

I am using the following piece of code to recursively iterate over a directory:

```
    for root, dirs, files in scandir.walk(IMAGES_ROOT):
      print timestr() + " - Walking %s..." % root
```

I also tried `os.walk` instead, but it gets stuck in the same directory every time. There are only files in that directory, no other directories or symlinks.

The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, I use Python 2.7 and the directory I am trying to traverse is on a network drive.

I can open the directory in my file browser without issues.

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: There is no error message. The program outputs "Walking NAME_OF_THAT_DIRECTORY..." and stays that way for hours.
Up to that point, it is able to traverse the directory tree pretty fast but then comes to a halt.

I also want to add that the tree is large with several thousand directories and several million files.

Comment: How do other utilities, such as `find` or `tree`, behave?

Comment: I just tried it on another machine and while it got stuck in the same directory as well, it did so only for a few seconds and then moved on.

Comment: `tree` and `find` work fine.